# Create Hand-Filled Form

Tags: spacing, formatting, line-spacing, vertical-spacing

I'm creating a form for people to print and fill out. Currently, I'm using

```
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\begin{document}
    I, \uline{\hskip 3cm}, instated \uline{\hfill}
\end{document}
```

The only problem is that in a paragraph, there isn't enough vertical space to fill out the form. `\spacing{1.3}` is pretty good, but if there are no form elements, I don't want the extra space.

The following is close:

```
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\begin{document}
    I, \raisebox{0pt}[2em]{\uline{\hskip 3cm}}, instated \raisebox{0pt}[2em]{\uline{\hfill}}
\end{document}
```

But the second line doesn't take any horizontal space (the `\hrule` seems to be ignored).

Is there a good way to fix my approach here, or should I use a different approach altogether?

Comment: The issue with your `\raisebox` variant is that `\raisebox` will first typeset its argument into a `\hbox` and in that the `\hfill` will not work.

Comment: @Skillmonlikestopanswers.xyz Thank you for mentioning `topanswers.xyz`, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `ulem` at all to draw some lines, instead you can use some low-level TeX and use `\leaders`, which has the syntax:

```
\leaders<box><skip>
```

It inputs `<box>` as many times as necessary to fill out `<skip>`. In addition we put a `\rule` of zero thickness in front of the line. The height of that `\rule` will determine the space reserved for the hand writing. In the following I assume that a human can write into a 6mm high space without issues.

The macro `\formline` I created will take an optional argument specifying the width of the horizontal skip (and hence the line), if you don't provide any it'll use `\hfill`, else it'll use `\hskip#1\relax`.

I put some dummy content around your form lines to show that the vertical spacing gets stretched on the text lines containing the form lines:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\newcommand\formline[1][\fill]
  {%
    \rule{0pt}{6mm}%
    \leaders\hbox{\rule[-1pt]{1pt}{.4pt}}\hskip #1\relax
    \null
  }

\usepackage{duckuments}

\begin{document}
\blindduck[1-]
I, \formline[3cm], instated \formline\\
\blindduck
I, \formline[3cm], instated \formline
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent answer. I went with `\newcommand{\field}[2][6mm]{\rule{0pt}{#1}\leaders\hbox{\rule[-1pt]{1pt}{.6pt}}\hskip#2\relax\null}` so I always specify the width of the field, and can optionally specify the height. I do see some irregularity in the underlines (since it's repeating a 1pt line over and over), but it doesn't show up when I print. Thanks so much!

Comment: @LimitedAtonement yes, those irregularities are usually errors during the anti-aliasing of the PDF viewers. I suggest when in doubt use `xpdf` to check on a big magnification, it does pretty precise rendering. And if still in doubt print a test page.